# CSS styling to remember a users votes (up and downvote)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using `Reactjs` and Firebase, I have a small voting app which lets you upvote or downvote an entry. Once logged in, you can vote on entries (currently they are just names) and they order themselves from most votes to least votes. When you hover over the voting icons, they change colors like so:
Normal:
[image]
Hover:
[image]

```
.downVote {
 align-items: center;
 font-size: 1.0em;
 padding-top: 2px;
 margin-right: 3px;
 float: right;
 color: #fb655a;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.downVote:hover {
 border-width: 0px;
 background-color: #fb655a;
 color: #000;
}
```

I want to find a way to keep the hover attributes active once the vote has been cast — which is an `:active(?)` state and have the Javascript or Firebase remember to keep the voting icon in that state for that user. So when a user votes on a few names and comes back to the page later, they will see which they have voted on and what their vote was.

I'm looking for ideas of how this will be achieved.

Currently, in firebase, I have the user's authenticated ID (uid) saved in each person name whom they have voted on, as either a 1 or -1 denoting an up or down vote. I'm sure that variable could be used, but I'm not sure how to tie that into the `Javascript` or `CSS`.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

---

**Edit**

---

The firebase layout:
[image]
So for this user vKl6r... (me in this case), when I log on, I should see the upvote button pressed next to the person named Test, since a 1 is stored.

Here is the layout of the each person's name whom can be voted on (with the voting icons)

```
    handleUpvote(id){
    this.props.upvotePlayer(id)
}

handleDownvote(id){
    this.props.downvotePlayer(id)
}

render(props){
    return(
        <div className="player fade-in">
            <span className="vote up"
            onClick={() => this.handleUpvote(this.playerId)}>
            &#9650;
            </span>
            <p className="playerContent">{this.playerContent}</p>
            <span className="vote down" 
            onClick={() => this.handleDownvote(this.playerId)}>
            &#9660;
            </span>

        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: for this problem it's better to make this icon into a component then set `onClick `React event on them

Comment: Can you post your React or JS code?

Comment: if your html is using custom attributes, you can use css to color that specific element: [vote-status="1"] { background-color: red; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are passing the props in, but if `this.playerContent` corresponds to the string 'test' in your screenshot then `this.voters` in your component should correspond to the object with people who have voted.

If that's correct then I'd then search for a key in this object with my uid and check if the value is 1.

```
this.voters[myUid] === 1
```

You need to pass your uid in as a prop. Or call auth() in componentDidmount to make sure you have your uid accessible.

If the key exists and teh value is 1 then I add a class of `.alreadyVotedOn` as I mentioned in my other post below. You can use a ternary operator or a simple && operator...

```
this.voters[myUid] === 1 && 'alreadyVotedOn'
```

Pop that into the className on your upvote button using template strings:

```
<span 
  className={{`vote up ${this.state.votedOn[name] === 1 && 'alreadyVotedOn'}`}} 
  onClick={() => this.handleUpvote(this.playerId)}>
   &#9650;
</span>
```

That should do the trick.

Repeat with -1 for the downvote button.

You don't have to do this all in the className attribute. You can also add custom data attributes like @doppl3r suggested in an earlier comment. The process is the same, just keeps your className attribute cleaner.

Instead of using a span you might want to use a button element to be semantically correct. Using a button also affords you access to the disabled attribute. You can pop the same logic into the disabled attribute to stop people voting more than once.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helps significantly. I was having trouble trying to access `uid` in my Player.jsx where this voting is taking place, and that's because the auth() and uid variable are both in my main App.js. So I see you suggest either calling auth to get all that information there, or pass it as a prop. That's helpful, thanks. One thing that confuses me is I don't have a prop for `voters.` I'm just doing a `let ref = firebase.database().ref('/players/' + playerId + '/voters');` in App.js to access the voters child and checking to see if the UID is there and if it equals 1 or -1. Will that work here too?

Comment: Yes, it will work here too. If you are already calling the data in app js then no need to call the same network request twice. Pass it down as a prop aswell. You save on network requests and your app is faster.

Comment: This is working very well -- and it was almost exactly as you laid it out. One more question — I have to reload the page for the player objects to display the correct voting icon changes. Meaning, if it's voted up at first and highlighted, and I click down vote, I must refresh for the change to take place. Is there a way to refresh each individual player as it is voted on? I tried forcing a re-render and calling componentDidMount after voting.

Comment: This would be down to how you are calling the firebase data. If you need to refresh then it sounds like you have only called it .once(), you need to switch the call to .on() so it continues to listen to changes. This should help https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events or create a new stack question for this and post the code where you call firebase for the votes object.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to create a CSS class for what you want the button to look like if it's been voted on, then conditionally apply className to the button if your database object of votes contains the name in the button.

The CSS class selector would be the same as the hover one you have now:

```
.alreadyVotedOn {
 border-width: 0px;
 background-color: #fb655a;
 color: #000;
}
```

Conditionally apply this class name to the button depending on whether it's been voted on:

```
<button className={{this.state.votedOn[name] === -1 ? 'alreadyVotedOn' : null}}>▼</button>
```

I used `this.state.votedOn[name] === -1` to detect whether something has been voted on because it sounds like you have an object with all the names of people a user has voted on somewhere in your firebase.

For this to work you want to load that object into the component and store it in state under the key 'votedOn'. You could do this with a databse call in componentDidMount, or pass the data in if you're using redux or mobx.

It's really hard to suggest the best way to do this because we have no understanding of how the data is shaped, how you are pulling it into the component or what the component code looks like. If you can share a screenshot of the relevant chunk in your database and code for the component we can be more useful.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I shared a screenshot in the original post with the firebase layout, as well as code where the person to be voted on and voting icons are generated and given a class. The firebase layout has each person who can be voted on (players), and then inside each player, theres a child called `voters` which has the unique ID of all the users who voted up or down on that player. I appreciate the help.